# Hypergeometric distribution mean.

Tags: probability

We have a box with 40 balls inside it, one for each child. 15 black balls and 25 white balls.
The reward for getting a black ball is noted Rb, and for white ball is noted Rw, where Rb > Rw.
I'm the 20th child in line to randomly pick a ball, and 2 children before me already got a black ball.
The last child in line gives me an offer that if I get a black ball and he doesn't, he'll pay me 2$ to switch balls with him.

What is my expected reward if I don't accept the deal?
What is my expected reward if I accept the deal?

I thought about using the mean formula of hipergeometric distribution but it does not take into account the 2 black balls chosen so its clearly not the way to go (I think).
What am I missing here? Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

By the time you get to pick, there are 13 black and 8 white balls left. If you don't accept the deal, then your expected winnings are simply

$$\boxed{ \frac{13}{21} \; R_B + \frac{8}{21} \; R_W }$$

Suppose you accept the deal. Now there are three cases to consider:

Case (1): $\quad$you draw White, the deal has no effect and you earn $R_W$;

$ \qquad \qquad \; \; $ the probability is $\dfrac{8}{21} $

Case (2): $\quad$you and the other child both draw Black, the deal has no effect and you earn $R_B$;

$ \qquad \qquad \; \; $ the probability is $\dfrac{13}{21}\cdot \dfrac{12}{20} = \dfrac{13}{35}$

Case (3): $\quad$you draw Black, the other child draws White, the deal holds and you earn \$($2+R_W$);

$ \qquad \qquad \; \; $ the probability is $\dfrac{13}{21}\cdot \dfrac{8}{20} = \dfrac{26}{105}$

Thus your expected winnings if you do accept the deal are

$$\begin{align}
& \; \frac{8}{21} \; R_W + \frac{13}{35} \; R_B + \frac{26}{105} \; (2+R_W)\\
\\
= \quad & \boxed{ \frac{22}{35} \; R_W + \frac{13}{35} \; R_B + \frac{52}{105} }
\end{align}$$

Comment: The other child is last in line, I don't see how his chances to get a black ball are 12/20 in case (2) for example.

Comment: Once you pick black, there are 12 black balls left out of a total of 20 balls. At that point, all people who haven't chosen yet have an equal chance of ending up with a black ball, regardless of their position in line. Intuitively, consider that as long as there are still 12 black balls out of 20 balls, there is no reason for any one person still in line to have a higher or lower probability of choosing a black ball than anyone else. Otherwise, methods like drawing straws would be hugely unfair to the last person drawing. If you're not convinced, try calculating as follows.

Comment: Let the next three people in line be $X, Y, Z$. Clearly $P(X_b)=\frac{12}{20}$. Now $P(Y_b)=P(X_b)P(Y_b|X_b)+P(X_w)P(Y_b|X_w)=\frac{12}{20} \cdot \frac{11}{19}+\frac{8}{20} \cdot \frac{12}{19}=\frac{12}{20}. Similarly, P(Z_b)=P(X_b and Y_b)P(Z_b|X_b and Y_b)+P(X_b and Y_w)P(Z_b|X_b and Y_w)+P(X_w and Y_b)P(Z_b|X_w and Y_b)+P(X_w and Y_w)P(Z_b|X_w and Y_w)=\frac{12}{20} \cdot \frac{11}{19} \cdot \frac{10}{18}+\frac{12}{20} \cdot \frac{8}{19} \cdot \frac{11}{18}+\frac{8}{20} \cdot \frac{12}{19} \cdot \frac{11}{18}+\frac{8}{20} \cdot \frac{7}{19} \cdot \frac{12}{18}=\frac{12}{20}$

Comment: And why have you inserted the 2$ into the probability calculation in case 3?

Comment: I also believe my winnings in case the deal is in effect should be 2+Rw. Right?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I forgot the balls were being **traded**, my solution just had you giving the other child the black ball. I've edited my solution to correct that error.